ESP32 Wroom Deep Sleep - High Current
I have a esp32-wroom-32d, (not a dev board, just the unit with headers). I went through the QA mentioned here (ESP_deep_sleep).
I am running the ULP example code using espress-if itself.
The example compiles and runs but it is not necessarily going into deep_sleep as it should
load:0x40080404,len:3496
entry 0x400805d0
W (119) spi_flash: Detected size(4096k) larger than the size in the binary image header(2048k). Using the size in the binary image header.
Not ULP wakeup, initializing ULP
Entering deep sleep

I checked the power profiler and it maintains 3.3mA. There is nothing connected to the board to any of the GPIOs. The active range is around 50mA, so it is in deep sleep but just not low enough.
I ran the example code as it was but it did not work so, the changes.
Any suggestions on how to get the deep_sleep current consumption to micro Amps?
/*
 * SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2023-2024 Espressif Systems (Shanghai) CO LTD
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense OR CC0-1.0
 */
/* ULP Example

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "esp_sleep.h"
#include "nvs.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "soc/sens_reg.h"
#include "soc/rtc_periph.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/rtc_io.h"
#include "ulp.h"
#include "ulp_main.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

extern const uint8_t ulp_main_bin_start[] asm("_binary_ulp_main_bin_start");
extern const uint8_t ulp_main_bin_end[]   asm("_binary_ulp_main_bin_end");

static void init_ulp_program(void);
static void update_pulse_count(void);

void app_main(void)
{
    /* If user is using USB-serial-jtag then idf monitor needs some time to
    *  re-connect to the USB port. We wait 1 sec here to allow for it to make the reconnection
    *  before we print anything. Otherwise the chip will go back to sleep again before the user
    *  has time to monitor any output.
    */
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));

    esp_sleep_wakeup_cause_t cause = esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause();
    if (cause != ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_ULP) {
        printf("Not ULP wakeup, initializing ULP\n");
        init_ulp_program();
    } else {
        printf("ULP wakeup, saving pulse count\n");
        // update_pulse_count();
    }

    printf("Entering deep sleep\n\n");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_sleep_enable_ulp_wakeup() );
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}

static void init_ulp_program(void)
{
    esp_err_t err = ulp_load_binary(0, ulp_main_bin_start,
            (ulp_main_bin_end - ulp_main_bin_start) / sizeof(uint32_t));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);

    // /* GPIO used for pulse counting. */
    // gpio_num_t gpio_num = GPIO_NUM_0;
    // int rtcio_num = rtc_io_number_get(gpio_num);
    // assert(rtc_gpio_is_valid_gpio(gpio_num) && "GPIO used for pulse counting must be an RTC IO");

    // /* Initialize some variables used by ULP program.
    //  * Each 'ulp_xyz' variable corresponds to 'xyz' variable in the ULP program.
    //  * These variables are declared in an auto generated header file,
    //  * 'ulp_main.h', name of this file is defined in component.mk as ULP_APP_NAME.
    //  * These variables are located in RTC_SLOW_MEM and can be accessed both by the
    //  * ULP and the main CPUs.
    //  *
    //  * Note that the ULP reads only the lower 16 bits of these variables.
    //  */
    // ulp_debounce_counter = 3;
    // ulp_debounce_max_count = 3;
    // ulp_next_edge = 0;
    // ulp_io_number = rtcio_num; /* map from GPIO# to RTC_IO# */
    // ulp_edge_count_to_wake_up = 10;

    // /* Initialize selected GPIO as RTC IO, enable input, disable pullup and pulldown */
    // rtc_gpio_init(gpio_num);
    // rtc_gpio_set_direction(gpio_num, RTC_GPIO_MODE_INPUT_ONLY);
    // rtc_gpio_pulldown_dis(gpio_num);
    // rtc_gpio_pullup_dis(gpio_num);
    // rtc_gpio_hold_en(gpio_num);

// #if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32
//     /* Disconnect GPIO12 and GPIO15 to remove current drain through
//      * pullup/pulldown resistors on modules which have these (e.g. ESP32-WROVER)
//      * GPIO12 may be pulled high to select flash voltage.
//      */
//     rtc_gpio_isolate(GPIO_NUM_12);
//     rtc_gpio_isolate(GPIO_NUM_15);
// #endif // CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32

    esp_deep_sleep_disable_rom_logging(); // suppress boot messages

    /* Set ULP wake up period to T = 20ms.
     * Minimum pulse width has to be T * (ulp_debounce_counter + 1) = 80ms.
     */
    ulp_set_wakeup_period(0, 20000);

    /* Start the program */
    err = ulp_run(&ulp_entry - RTC_SLOW_MEM);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);
}

static void update_pulse_count(void)
{
    const char* nvs_namespace = "plusecnt";
    const char* count_key = "count";

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( nvs_flash_init() );
    nvs_handle_t handle;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( nvs_open(nvs_namespace, NVS_READWRITE, &handle));
    uint32_t pulse_count = 0;
    esp_err_t err = nvs_get_u32(handle, count_key, &pulse_count);
    assert(err == ESP_OK || err == ESP_ERR_NVS_NOT_FOUND);
    printf("Read pulse count from NVS: %5" PRIu32"\n", pulse_count);

    /* ULP program counts signal edges, convert that to the number of pulses */
    uint32_t pulse_count_from_ulp = (ulp_edge_count & UINT16_MAX) / 2;
    /* In case of an odd number of edges, keep one until next time */
    ulp_edge_count = ulp_edge_count % 2;
    printf("Pulse count from ULP: %5" PRIu32"\n", pulse_count_from_ulp);

    /* Save the new pulse count to NVS */
    pulse_count += pulse_count_from_ulp;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_set_u32(handle, count_key, pulse_count));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_commit(handle));
    nvs_close(handle);
    printf("Wrote updated pulse count to NVS: %5" PRIu32"\n", pulse_count);
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

does your module have radios on it?  Are they turned all the way off?  I don't see code controlling the radios.

Yes, I tested by explicitly disabling the WiFi and Bluetooth but no changes in consumption. So did not include them in the code.

I was using a board (Similar to this) to connect the ESP32-Wroom module, which was drawing the current. I was using it for the headers since the bare module doesn't have any.
Fix:
I soldered the connections onto the bare ESP32-Wroom-module (as per the pic below) and ran the Deep_Sleep_Wake_up example from Arduino IDE and the deep sleep current is 5uA. I am using the ESP-prog as show in the pic to connect the ESP-Wroom-Module.
The way it works: The ESP programmer is used to power the Espress-if module. It acts as the Vin for the Power kit and the Vout is taken from the Module itself. Therefore, You can measure the actual current consumed in deep sleep.
The example code (from Arduino IDE) I run, it wakes up the chip every 5 seconds from deep sleep and you can see that the chip is in active mode and consumes current in mA.
ESPRESS-IF Doc

Output from the power-profiler:
I am using a power profiler kit. The connections to that are same as with the JOULESCOPE, I used this a reference for my connections.

Edit:
I have added more details for better clarity such as the link of the board I was previously using and throw more light onto the final solution.

rmknan - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. However some site members are unclear what the answer really is. || I think the only part of this post which is the actual answer is the first paragraph, and the rest is saying how you are proving the solution. Is that correct? || You mentioned "a board" that you were using for its headers (as the ESP32-Wroom module didn't have any) and saying that was consuming current too. It's unclear what "board" that is - I don't think it is mentioned or shown anywhere, is it?

(continued) Looking at the wiring diagram in this answer, the current to run the ESP-Prog wouldn't be measured by the Joulescope, so the ESP-Prog is not the "board" which you're blaming - is it? || If you can clarify more about what was the cause, and clearly separate that from any explanation of your different wiring which does not show a problem (which is what I think you are showing in the diagram in this answer), that would help. So, please clarify where possible. TY

Hello, I have added more details to my answer. Lmk if any doubts.

rmknan - Hi, Thanks for the update. So just to be clear: The problem was that extra current taken by your board like this made you think that the ESP32 wasn't going into deep sleep. But in fact the ESP32 was going into deep sleep, and that is what the part of your answer below "fix" is showing. Is that correct? TY

Yes, The fix shows that if you want to measure the deep sleep current as indicated in the datasheet then you would have to do it on the bare module. Using a dev board which may not be meant for low power would not match it.
